# Trouble reading user accessible files

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am using `nativescript-mediafilepicker` as means of choosing a file, and this can read external storage successfully (I have downloaded a PDF to the 'downloads' folder on iOS and I am able to pick it.) I then try to load the file using the file system module from nativescript library, and this fails because it is listed as `NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught Error: You can‚Äôt save the file ‚Äúcom.xxxxxx‚Äù because the volume is read only.` This doesn't make sense as I am trying to read anyway - I don't understand where the saving part is from. The error comes from `fileSystemModule.File.fromPath()` line.

Something to note that `file['file']` is `file:///Users/adair/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82F397CE-B0B3-4ADD-AD52-805265C7AC49/data/Containers/Data/Application/7B47A8BD-6DBA-42CF-8792-38A8C5E61174/tmp/com.xxxxxx/test.pdf`

Is the file automatically being pulled to an application specific directory after this media picker?

```js
getFiles() {
      let extensions = [];
      if (app.ios) {
        extensions = [kUTTypePDF]; // you can get more types from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mobilecoreservices/uttype
      } else {
        extensions = ["pdf"];
      }
      const mediaFilePicker = new Mediafilepicker();
      const filePickerOptions = {
        android: {
          extensions,
          maxNumberFiles: 1,
        },
        ios: {
          extensions,
          maxNumberFiles: 1,
        },
      };
      masterPermissions
        .requestPermissions([masterPermissions.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,masterPermissions.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        .then((fulfilled) => {
          console.log(fulfilled);
          mediaFilePicker.openFilePicker(filePickerOptions);
          mediaFilePicker.on("getFiles", function (res) {
            let results = res.object.get("results");
            let file = results[0];
            console.dir(file);
            let fileObject = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(file["file"]);
            console.log(fileObject);
          });

          mediaFilePicker.on("error", function (res) {
            let msg = res.object.get("msg");
            console.log(msg);
          });

          mediaFilePicker.on("cancel", function (res) {
            let msg = res.object.get("msg");
            console.log(msg);
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue I have experienced is resultant of the expectation of File.fromPath and what is returned by the file picker. File picker is returning a "file://path" URI, and File.fromPath is expecting a string of just "path".

Simply using the following instead is enough.

```js
let fileObject = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(file["file"].replace("file://","");
```